# Xcode 9: Cannot build application with new (default) build system in titanium

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator

> [ERROR] note: Using new build system [ERROR] error: Could not delete
>   because it was not created by the  build system and it is not a
>   subfolder of derived data. [ERROR] ** CLEAN FAILED **

Answer (score 0):

Use must use the last version of Titanium : 7.5.0.GA to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Titanium `7.4.0.GA` and greater allows you to develop using Xcode 10 under the hood. If you're running an older SDK and have Xcode 10 installed you'll need to either download Xcode 9 or use Xcode Select to change what you're compiling against.

You can get more information here: https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2018/10/running-xcode-9-xcode-10-side-side/